# alternative to jdbc resultset rs.next()

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset

I have a first resultset within which I have to iterate through userids and for each userid, I have to perform several select count(*)'s all of which return single valued outputs. If you haven't understood what I said, please follow the pseudo code below:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select userid from tablename");
while(rs.next()){
    String userid = rs.getString("userId");
    ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery("select count(*) as cnt1 from xxx.... where userId = "+userId);
    if(rs1.next())
        String count1 = rs1.getString("cnt1");
    rs1.close();
    ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery("select count(*) as cnt2...");
    if(rs2.next())
        String count2 = rs2.getString("cnt2");
    rs2.close();
    ....
    rs10.close();
```

Since this is inefficient, I was hoping to get past Resultset each time by writing some sort of direct query to retrieve each different count like

```
String  cnt1 = stmt.executeQuery("select count(*) as noE from useractiontable where curr_action='edit'"  + " and userId = " + userId).getString("noE");
```

I know something like this cannot be done without using rs.next() each time. Is prepare statement the way to go? Is there another way? Appreciate any pointers in this regard.

Comment: If your connection allows it, use multiple statements in a single query.

Comment: because you count, you could use `union` here (each result being a specific count)

Comment: Executing a query on a statement object will close any previously opened result set of that same statement. You need to use multiple statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `group by` to retrieve all the user with count(*)

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select userid,count(*) from tablename group by userid");
```

Comment: Your answer is close enough to what I'm trying to accomplish. You have hinted me on how I could club all my resultsets to one query using group by. I guess that's the way to go. But your exact query is not right as I have not written my select statements clearly in the question. Nonetheless, I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you can do all the DB work in one query and then just have one result set to read. It would be much more efficient and much cleaner code. I am thinking something like:

```
select userid, count(*) as cnt
from tablename t inner join othertablename ot on t.userid = ot.userid
group by userid
```

If you have other columns in `tablename` that you want, you would add them to the select and to the group-by. For example:

```
select userid, username, count(*) as cnt
from tablename t inner join othertablename ot on t.userid = ot.userid
group by userid, username
```

The above queries will not return userid's with a count of zero. If you want the ones with zeros, use an outer join (and make the counting logic deal with the null case):

```
select userid, username, isnull(count(ot.userid), 0) as cnt
from tablename t left outer join othertablename ot on t.userid = ot.userid
group by userid, username
```